# Finding time until oldest stick table entry expires

Tags: haproxy

I'm attempting to implement an accurate Retry-After for rate limiting to replicate in haproxy what we have in another system. I've created a rate limiting configuration to return a 429 if the user exceeds our acceptable rate limit, it works perfectly. It sets the X-RateLimit-Remaining header to give them a count down until they're out of quota.

```
frontend www_http_https
...

  tcp-request connection track-sc1 src table hour_throttle
  acl hour_abuser src_http_req_rate(hour_throttle) gt 5500
  acl flag_hour_abuse sc1_inc_gpc0(hour_throttle) gt 0

  http-request set-var(txn.req_counter) src_http_req_rate(hour_throttle)
  http-request set-var(txn.abuse_count) int(5500),sub(txn.req_counter)

  http-response add-header X-RateLimit-Remaining %[var(txn.abuse_count)]
  http-response add-header X-RateLimit-Limit %[int(5500)]
  http-response add-header X-RateLimit-Period %[int(3600)]

  http-request deny deny_status 429 if hour_abuser

frontend hour_throttle
  stick-table type ip size 1m expire 3600s store gpc0,http_req_rate(3600s)
  tcp-request connection track-sc1 src
  acl flag_ratelimit_abuser src_get_gpc0 gt 0
```

However I've been unable to find a way to determine the number of seconds until sufficient table entries for their IP will expire allowing them to make requests again. All the examples I've found have a canned "Retry-After: 60" rather than the actual number of second left before they can try again (ie. "Retry-After: 13" or "Retry-After: 122")

I've been attempting to play with the store-response keyword to see if I could have the time of the request in the table entry or such to get this information, to no success so far. Is there a way to retrieve this information? Perhaps through the new Lua interface?

Thanks.